# Speed of rendering 2D graphics in D3D

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

Which way to render 2D graphics is faster in d3d? Using sprites or texturing quads/other polys?

Answer (score 2):

By using sprites do you mean D3DXCreateSprite etc? This almost certainly uses textured quads under the hood, and batches up the draw calls to make things fast. I'd suggest using this and only investigate manually creating quads if this isn't sufficiently fast.